# Citrix Reciever ignores mouse and keyboard entry

Tags: osx-mavericks, citrix-receiver

Using the Citrix Receiver/Viewer to remotely access my Windows 7 desktop.

Occasionally, when I switch to another OS X desktop (using gesturing) then switch back to the desktop that contains the Citrix Viewer, the keyboard/mouse entry is ignored.

What's the most reliable way to restore keyboard/mouse entry? Is there a way to prevent this?

Citrix Viewer: 11.8.2 (255309)

** edit **

Using bluetooth keyboard and trackpad.

Tried:

- swipe left and right - no effect
- swipe up and down - no effect
- <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> seems to work, but not relably.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using keyboard/mouse peripherals or built-in? If so, what happens when you take them out of the USB slot and put them back in? And just so we cover the obvious: the window has focus when you switch back correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

appears to be a known issue - http://support.citrix.com/article/ctx200212

Keyboard Input Fails in Citrix Session from Receiver for Mac with OSX 10.9.5

Solution

To resolve this issue, complete the following steps:

1.Press Command + Tab and exit the session to the local Mac desktop.

2.Press Command + Tab again to return to the session.

The keyboard functions thereafter in that session.

Problem Cause

Citrix has created a fix for this issue that will be available in the next Public release of the Receiver for Mac version 11.9. The fix can be verified by testing the Receiver for Mac Tech Preview.

Receiver for Mac 11.9 Tech Preview
https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/mac/receiver-for-mac-11-9.html.